Example request: Lie group $G$ whose Levi Decomposition $G = RS$ has $R \cap S \neq 1$
Let $G$ be a connected Lie group. The Levi decomposition (in its usual form) asserts that the Lie algebra of $G$ splits as a semi-direct product of its solvable radical and a semisimple subalgebra. Exponentiating these two subalgebras, we get closed subgroups $R,S \subset G$ with $R$ maximal normal, solvable, and $S$ semisimple.
When $G$ is simply connected, this article (see also this question) claims that $G = RS$, $R \cap S = 1$, and therefore $G = R \rtimes S$.
I am interested in the non-simply connected case. I believe (see proposition 2.5 here) the correct statement says "$G = RS$ and $R \cap S$ is discrete."
Question:

Is the above statement correct? It should follow from the simply connected case by applying the above theorem to the universal cover of $G$, so I suppose I am really asking if it is the strongest statement you can make in this situation. That is,

Is there an example of a Lie group $G$ with $R \cap S \neq 1$?


By the above theorem, the universal cover of such an example must be a semidirect product of a solvable group by a semisimple lie group. Moreover, $R \cap S$ must be normal (hence, central) in $S$. Then I am led to look at quotients of groups like $R^2 \rtimes \widetilde{SL_2(\mathbb{R})}$, but it seems all of these quotients have $R\cap S = 1$ also. From here, I don't know what to think.
